ToolbarItem hover color in Windows and macCatalyst
In my .NET 8 MAUI application, for Windows and macCatalyst, I have the ToolbarItem defined like this:
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem
        Clicked="OnAddNewItem"
        Order="Primary"
        Priority="0"
        Text="{lang:Translate Add}">
        <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
            <FontImageSource
                FontFamily="FAS"
                Glyph="{x:Static hlp:FontAwesomeIcons.Plus}"
                Size="35"
                Color="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White},
                                        Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

The issue is about the hover color. As you can see in the screenshot below, if you hover the mouse on the menu, the color is black.

I like to change this color but I can't find how.

Do you want the font color to remain white when you are hovering or not hovering?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT yes, correct

I reproduced your problem, I found that on Android, when clicking on the ToolbarItem, the font color remains the white color, but on Windows platform when clicking on the ToolbarItem, the font color is still black, so I judge that this is a bug, you can post this issue to Github MAUI

Thank you so much
